# Remotely manage files from a Windows machine

Tags: file-sharing, filemanager, remote

I have a home server/media center using Ubuntu 14.04, and I need to manage files on it from my Windows 7 machine (same LAN). At the moment I am using TeamViewer, but it's not really what I want, and I couldn't find a better solution.

The files are in Samba shared folders, but if I perform a write action on them (rename, edit, add file), it changes the owner.

Is there a Windows app that I can use so I remotely manage my Ubuntu filesystem without screwing the file ownership and chmods ? (E.g. something like Total Commander, but with SSH/remote acces capabilities ; or something that allows me to "mount" the shared folders so I can edit the files like I'm doing it directly in Ubuntu) I'm not looking for RDP software, I have TeamViewer for that, only something to manage files.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you have installed the OpenSSH server on the Ubuntu machine,then you should be able to use any SFTP/SCP-based file manager from the Windows box. My favorite is [WinSCP](http://winscp.net/eng/index.php) but [FileZilla](https://filezilla-project.org/) is also popular.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**xrdp**](http://www.xrdp.org/)

```
sudo apt-get install xrdp
```

xrdp: An open source remote desktop protocol(rdp) server.

check this for more information and configuration
http://www.tweaking4all.com/software/linux-software/use-xrdp-remote-access-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: I'm sorry, but this is not the kind of software I'm looking for. I'll edit my post  to be more clear